# Get parent product URL through magento API

Tags: php, api, magento, magento-1.7

I'd like to get the parent URL for a simple product that is associated with a grouped product (the "parent") through the magento API.

This is how I do it inside the magento app:

```
<?php if($_product->getTypeId() == "simple"): ?>
<?php $parentIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')->getParentIdsByChild($_product->getId()); ?>
```

Now I need a call like this for the API, so I can get the grouped product URL (that has the simple product associated) when I input the "sku" of the simple product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should creating a Custom API for to do this. You can read how create custom API here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html
In native API methods is only one method list
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductTypes/productTypes.html